# Can I introduce Angular 2 to an existing JS/jQuery/PHP project?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, angular, architecture

I have an existing project (JS/jQuery and PHP for the backend) running. It's quite huge and still in development.

I'm now looking to introduce Angular 2 in this project in order to progressively clean up the front end and start from good bases. **New modules will be created using Angular 2** and existing modules will progressively be converted.

The app is running on a **single page** using ajax to load data from the API. And my entry point is the **index.php** which I cannot discard because it integrate all the loading logic of the project.

Therefore, can I introduce Angular 2 in this project and if "yes" how can I process?

Any suggestions and examples are welcome.

Comment: This is really a shot in the dark. You can always try to get to know Angular 2 and build a small module of the greater project. With that finished, you can see if it suits (yourself and) the greater project and refactor the project.

Comment: The main issues I'm facing so far is that most of the examples are showing index.html as the entry point, and then eventually templates get loaded in different ways (including .php), which make sense.But at the opposite I've not found yet the possibility to initiate Angular 2 script from the .php file. I'm actively looking for good examples in this way.

Comment: can initiate angular in any file type or file name that outputs html page. Using `.html` is just simpler for most development since it is a static resource file that is agnostic to server type or language used

Comment: in my experience, jquery doesn't play too nicely with angular because the page doesn't reload. It's not insurmountable, but can be a pain to work with.

Answer (score 0):

This is the way how I converted my existing ASP.NET MVC 5 application to Angular2. Use the same configuration files and convert your php application. 
[Using Angular 2 with TypeScript](http://www.mithunvp.com/using-angular-2-asp-net-mvc-5-visual-studio/)